# how to display 3 divs in a row using nth child property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have doubt about assigning 3 div in a main container `div` using the CSS `nth child` property. Can anyone suggest me the formula?

```css
.containerbox {
  display: flex;
}
.pricing-container:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: You can display them in a row without `nth-child` too. What is the use-case here?

Comment: can you please show me an example?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to select 3rd element or display 3 divs in a row. You need to show us your expected output for us to help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to use nth-child? 

Do you have any examples of what you're trying to acomplish?

Comment: I want to display 3 divs in a row. The css code is :                        .containerbox{
   display: flex;
   
  }
  .pricing-container:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  
 
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  padding-left:-100px;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using flexbox, you will need to use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent container. Set `width: 30%` on the child items, so that they wrap after the third item.

No need to use `nth-child` in your case and 30% width is used to compensate for the `margin: 10px 1%`

```css
.containerbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pricing-container {
  width: 30%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerbox">
  <div class="pricing-container">1</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">2</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">3</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">4</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">5</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">6</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">7</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">8</div>
  <div class="pricing-container">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, Syam :) Next time please make sure you add your code in the question to avoid any down votes from the community.

Comment: Sorry my friend. Next time I will add the code with the question.;-)